# Office ribbon for WPF 4.0

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, ribbon

It is rumoured that WPF 4.0 would deliver us an out-of-the-box Office Ribbon.

> A new WPF Ribbon Control will be
>   available for download shortly after
>   the release of WPF 4. [[1](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/26/wpf-4-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)]

Now my internet and MSDN search turned out to be fruitless, and as far as I know, it would be release after the .NET 4.0 framework would launch. My search lead me to the Office plugin ribbon controls and the CTP prereleased before the release of .net 4.0 with a limited featureset.

So my question is: does anyone know if and when Microsoft will release this Office Ribbon with the framework? Or if they don't a nice press note saying that they ditched the project.

Also if anyone has experience with the Ribbon I'm talking about, will this Ribbon work in a partial trusted environment?

My thanks will be ever lasting! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be old news to you now but there wasn't a selected answer so here you go:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534.aspx

You can download the source, examples, and assemblies for including a ribbon.  The documentation can be found on MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.aspx.

Simple example from a project that includes the 4.0 version of the RibbonControlsLibrary.dll

```
<Window x:Class="WpfRibbonApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
        Title="MainWindow"
        x:Name="RibbonWindow"
        Width="640" Height="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ribbon:Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon" Title="Ribbon Title">
            <ribbon:Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
                <ribbon:RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Icon.ico" />
            </ribbon:Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
            <ribbon:Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
                <ribbon:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar >
                    <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="QATButton1" 
                                         SmallImageSource="Icon.ico" />
                    <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="QATButton2" 
                                         SmallImageSource="Icon.ico" />
                </ribbon:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
            </ribbon:Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
            <ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
                <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu SmallImageSource="Icon.ico">
                    <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Hello _Ribbon"
                                                      x:Name="MenuItem1"
                                                      ImageSource="Icon.ico"/>
                </ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu>
            </ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <ribbon:RibbonTab x:Name="HomeTab" 
                              Header="Home">
                <ribbon:RibbonGroup x:Name="Group1" 
                                    Header="Group1">
                    <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="Button1"
                                         LargeImageSource="Icon.ico"
                                         Label="Button1" />
                    <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="Button2"
                                         SmallImageSource="Icon.ico"
                                         Label="Button2" />
                    <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="Button3"
                                         SmallImageSource="Icon.ico"
                                         Label="Button3" />
                    <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="Button4"
                                         SmallImageSource="Icon.ico"
                                         Label="Button4" />
                </ribbon:RibbonGroup>
            </ribbon:RibbonTab>
        </ribbon:Ribbon>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Produces something that looks like this:
[image: Example ribbon]

Comment: Nice.. we went with a third party control in the end though :) Looking at the download page dates of this ribbon it seems it came out 4 months after I was looking for it..

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [WPF 3.5 ribbon](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-ribbon-walkthrough.aspx)?

Comment: Yeah.. thats one of the prerelease I was talking about :) I can be found on codeplex, but I have not found the official Microsoft MSDN download awesome ribbon here link..

Answer (score 1):

It should work in partial trust unless they make a huge mistake :). Things not allowed in partial trust are:

- Connecting directly to SQL
- Reflection
- a few other things

Shouldn't be doing that sort of thing in a UserControl (even if it is a bit fancy...)

Comment: Yeah, and among those "few other things" are Bitmap Effects, like drop shadows.. Guess where those might be used :)

Comment: True, but I believe those are supposed to be refactored out of the Ribbon for 4.0, but as I said - pending Microsoft implementation which is always good clean family entertainment :)

EDIT: Best link at hand: http://blog.actiprosoftware.com/post/2010/03/31/Preview-of-upcoming-Ribbon-for-WPF-updates.aspx

Comment: "All outer glows no longer use bitmap effects, which are not supported by Microsoft in .NET 4.0.  WPF Studio 2010.1 moves its minimum requirements to .NET 3.5 SP1.  We have taken advantage of .NET 3.5 SP1’s shader effects to achieve outer glows now."

Seems like one less issue to worry about indeed.. Still do not know when or if it will be released.. :(